# trouble with creating file logs

Tags: r

I want to output a log of my R session that basically captures everything that would come up in the console and saves it out. I tried using sink(), but it just captures the printed output instead of the commands and then the printed output; and it suppresses the printed output in the console space when active. Is there a command / package, that just saves basically everything that comes out in the console into a text file?

I apologize if this has been asked and answered, but when I search I just keep getting information on running log regressions, or issues logging in.